# Found unanswered old question

Tags: discussion

I just found this old unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835322/jackson-object-mapper-is-not-using-the-mappers-setdateformat-or-setserializati) in StackOverflow. Do we have policy to delete these kind of question or we just left there. I want to confirm the policy before raising flag there.

Comment: There are over 1 million questions on Stack Overflow with no answers. Please don't flag these.

Comment: What @Bill means is don't flag the _unanswered questions_, only the 8 million answered ones. >:) `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 7):

Unanswered questions aren't bad.  [The system *automatically* culls them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) under certain conditions.  This question looks genuinely answerable, so I don't think it should be removed.

Don't flag a question/answer *because* it's old; flag it if there's genuinely something that a moderator should step in to deal with:

- Plagiarism
- Spam that has managed to fly under the radar

This is of course a very incomplete list, but the idea is not to bring it to the attention of the mods unless they *really* need to step in.

Comment: If the user has less than 2K rep, they still have to flag it to be closed.  that's what I meant by this particular flagging.  I'll be more than happy to clarify.

Comment: I thought you might, but the way you worded it could easily have been interpreted as *flag for moderator attention*, and then we have to decline the custom flag asking for closure. Thanks for removing it!